# How do I run GNU Typist/gtypist on a Mac?

Tags: gnu

I'm a little familiar with command line but I'm still having problems running GNU Typist/gtypist. http://www.gnu.org/software/gtypist/

Can anyone give me really basic step-by-step instructions for a Mac?

Answer (score 30):

Install using Homebrew

```
brew install gnu-typist
gtypist
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also install it directly from the sources (note that for building from the sources you have to install XCode - it's free and you can download it from App Store):

1. Get the source of gnu typist

   http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gtypist/gtypist-2.9.tar.gz
2. Get the source of ncurses

   I am downloading it from GNU pages here:

   ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses//ncurses-6.0.tar.gz.sig

   But you can get most recent version directly from maintainer's page:

   ftp://ftp.invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.tar.gz
3. Create place where you want to have all the stuff

   mkdir ~/opt/usr
4. Build ncurses - pay attention to --enable-widec

   ./configure --enable-widec --with-shared --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/

   make; make install
5. Build gnutypist

   export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/opt/usr/lib"

   export CFLAGS="-I$HOME/opt/usr/include"

   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/

   make; make install
6. Run gnutypist

   cd $HOME/opt/usr/bin

   ./gtypist

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to brew you can use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) (macos package manager)

Installation command:

```
sudo port install gtypist
```

Link to the port summary page:

https://ports.macports.org/port/gtypist/summary